# Error: Expecting ")" before end of parameters

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make a class called "Move" for a bigger assignment. In this class, there a 2 "Move" Constructors: one that takes in only a change in row and column (2 parameters) and calls the move "Move", and one that takes in a move name, a change in row, and a change in column (3 parameters).

But when I try to compile my .java file it tells me that its expecting a ")" before the constructor is done defining what parameters it need.

```
public class Move {

    private String moveName;
    private int rowDelta;
    private int colDelta;

    public Move(int rowDelta, int colDelta) {
        this("Move", rowDelta, colDelta);
    }

    public Move(String moveName; int rowDelta; int colDelta) {
        this.moveName = moveName;
        this.rowDelta = rowDelta;
        this.colDelta = colDelta;
    }

    public int getRowDelta() {
        return rowDelta;
    }

    public int getColDelta() {
        return colDelta;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return moveName;
    }

}
```

The errors it gives me are as follows:

```
Move.java:11: error: ')' expected
    public Move(String moveName; int rowDelta; int colDelta) {
                               ^
Move.java:11: error: ';' expected
    public Move(String moveName; int rowDelta; int colDelta) {
                                                           ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Separate elements in parameter lists with `,`. Why do you do it in one place and not the other...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`;` are for ending statements.  So you shouldn't be using them to separate parameters:

```
public Move(String moveName; int rowDelta; int colDelta)
```

Use `,` instead:

```
public Move(String moveName, int rowDelta, int colDelta)
```

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. (Is it obvious I'm a java novice?)

Answer (score 4):

Learn Java sytax, you should be using commas instead of semicolon. Replace this:

```
Move(String moveName; int rowDelta; int colDelta)
```

With

```
Move(String moveName, int rowDelta, int colDelta)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this

`public Move(String moveName; int rowDelta; int colDelta) {`

to

`public Move(String moveName, int rowDelta, int colDelta) {`

I think you got confused with `for` loop. These are not `statements` to have a semicolon at the end. They are just `parameters` of a method which should be separated by `,`

Answer (score 2):

Use commas to separate between values that are passed inside the function.

You can use ";" only in for loop to separate parameters

Answer (score 1):

This `public Move(String moveName; int rowDelta; int colDelta)` is wrong, you need

```
public Move(String moveName, int rowDelta, int colDelta) // comma, not semi-colon
```